# PHP Select all variables which are equal to 1

Tags: php

I am trying to get an SQL-query to be dynamic.

These are the steps I'm taking:

**Step 1:**

```
//Here the user sets which table fields will be used:
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1"> ID
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1"> name
<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"> email
```

**Step 2:**

```
//Here I see what fields the user wants to use and set a variable to 1
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == "1")
{
    $form_id='1';
}
//etc etc
?>
```

**Step 3:**

```
//And finally here's the sql query
$sql = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
```

Now I need to set the fields that the user selected to the query.

For example if the user checks **only** `id` and `name`, then it should look like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select id, name from $table");
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I found your question a little bit unclear but after editing it I think it's more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not instead push all of the field names into an array instead of setting disparate variables?

```
$fields = [];
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == 1) {
    $fields[] = 'id';
}
```

Then you should just be able to implode the array together in order to get your select columns:

```
$fields = implode(', ', $fields);
```

Also, @h2ooooo is correct, please avoid using `mysql_` functions. They are depracated and will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is to check which parameters are set and equal to one and push the column name into an array if that's the case.

You can then loop through the array and concatenate the fields to the query, making it *dynamic*.

The biggest concern here is that you're using [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions which are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). I recommend using [PDO](https://www.google.is/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20pdo) since I find them comfortable and handy to use but [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) is also viable.

With PDO and mysqli you'll be able to use [prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which are **the best way to prevent injections** so please use them.

**Solution**

Using the [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator, we can check which parameters are set and assign the field names accordingly.

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == 1 ? 'id' : null;
$name = isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == 1 ? 'name' : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] == 1 ? 'email' : null;
```

I do this becuse I find the ternary operator *prettier* than multiple if-statements.

Let's construct an array with the variables that we just created:

```
$parameters = array($id, $name, $email);
```

By simply checking which fields are not `null` we can easily construct the columns array.

```
$columns = array();
foreach($parameters as $column)
{
    if($column != null)
    {
        $columns[] = $column;
    }
}
```

Finally we can [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the columns together, separating them with a comma:

```
$activeColumns = implode(",", $columns);
```

So you can use `$activeColumns` as a part of your query, which is then recommend to be prepared afterwards.

Comment: This is more or less what @watcher answered but I had already started writing the answer so I let it stay.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use ! empty() function instead of isset() && $_post['id']==1

```
$select_fields = array();
if(!empty($_POST['id']))
    $select_fields[] = 'id';
if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    $select_fields[] = 'name';
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
    $select_fields[] = 'email';

$query_fields = implode(', ', $select_fields);

$sql = mysql_query("select $query_fields from $table");
```